# How do I create an Azure webjob using Java with Eclipse and Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I would like to create a scheduled webjob using Java to archive my data once a day. My plan, to minimize dependencies in the webjob itself, is to simply make an Http call to a running instance of my main application so that it can take care of the rest. The problem I am having is that after the webjob is successfully uploaded, I click run, it succeeds, and then fails instantly after. Only the success is logged, so I have absolutely no idea what is causing the failure. I am hoping someone with a bit more experience can walk me through the process to help me figure out what I am missing.

The Java code looks something like this:

```
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        Integer responseCode = null;
        try {
            URL serverUrl = new URL(endpoint);

            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("Status: " + responseCode + " - " + httpConnection.getResponseMessage());

            return responseCode;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (responseCode != null) {
                System.out.println("Status: " + responseCode + " - " + httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpConnection != null) {
                httpConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return 400;
```

Simplified, but just know that it runs perfectly fine on its own.

My process has been to export this code as a jar file and then compress the jar file along with a batch file into a zip.

The batch file reads:

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
set CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
java -jar archive-webjob.jar
```

And I have already tried using different jdks, 1.8.0_202 being the most recent.

Elsewhere, I have seen other files such as a web.config or a settings.job being used, but I haven't seen any difference using them myself.

As for my settings on Azure, always-on is set to true, along with Tomcat 8.5 (auto), Java 1.8 (auto), 64bit, and the minimal security configs.

Unfortunately I have had a very difficult time finding resources on how to do this. So please bear with me if I'm missing something obvious.

FYI, unfortunately Azure functions are off the table for me, as my company does not permit deployment using the Azure CLI, though I'm sure that would have been a great solution instead.

Thanks in advance for any useful information.

Comment: so what is the problem with the above code

Comment: Good question, ended up figuring this out on my own and provided an answer below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

So later on the logs *did* end up detailing the failures. The problem was that I was compressing the wrong jar file (the one that I manually exported on eclipse), which did not have a 'Main-Class' property in the `MANIFEST.MF` file. To save anyone experiencing difficulties this this some time, I'll go ahead and clearly outline the steps that I took.

1. Write the Java code and ensure it runs locally. Note that once uploaded, you won't be able to make a request to localhost or a private address, such as SO - but of course your deployed instances endpoints will work.
2. The run.bat file that worked for me actually looks like this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin
java -jar AppName-Version-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The 'jar-with-dependencies' postfix is the result of:

3. Maven plugin (of course, ways to do this with gradle/ant/command line as well):

```
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.otherPackages.MainClassName</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The key step that I was missing: as mentioned, although a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file was generated, it did not include a 'Main-Class' attribute (despite the implementation of the maven-assembly-plugin above).

4. Simply make the file in `src/main/resources` with the following contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: com.otherPackages.MainClassName
```

5. `mvn clean package` will generate a `AppName-Version-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in the target folder (no need to manually export as a jar), which will have a detailed `MANIFEST.MF` file that includes the Main-Class property this time.
6. Compress the `AppName-Version-jar-with-dependencies.jar` along with the `run.bat` file into a .zip
7. Upload the .zip file to Azure and the Webjob should work as expected.

Hope this saves someone a bit of time. I'd feel guilty if I didn't at least document my day and a half trying to figure this out.